# Riggify deform error

Tags: rigging, error, rigify

Can someone please tell me why it's deforming this way? it always deforms in the same sort of line wherever I rotate the head.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your neck bone influences: that line probably arise where vertices with "head only" weight are contiguous to vertices with "head and neck" weights. Use the smooth brush and the smear brush to even out the transition on both vertex groups (Head and neck). Check also if there are influences from vertex groups others than head and neck.